# Как при чтении csv файла с помощью opencsv добавить строку в конец последней прочитанной строки?

Tags: java, csv

Возник такой вопрос, допустим я построчно считываю csv файл,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если первое поле равно определенной строке, то добавляю строку в конец текущей строки. Допустим была строка Шоколадка,1,50,40.00 а после добавления пусть будет Шоколадка,1,50,40.00,2,60,50.00. Подозреваю, что так нельзя сделать и надо использовать CSVWriter, каким образом можно решить проблему?

Comment: Канечно так нельзя делать, надо структурировать данные с помощью объектов

Answer (score 0):

По идее CSVReader только  считывает в память данные CSV. Вам нужно будет считать данные в память (в данном случае это массив nextline), манипуляции со строками и после этого записать в файл результату при помощи CSVWriter.